# Performance groupBy

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a code similar to this:

```
df = transformation(df)
df = df.groupBy("f1").agg(agg1, agg2, agg3)
df.collect()
```

The aggregation functions do not contain any window (we could assume they are the `F.sum`of three different fields). Is there any case in which the operations in the method `transformation` are performed more than once if there is nothing persisted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the link and perform groupby operation:

1. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html